# Changing the colour or checkbox in MultiselectList in Windows Phone

Tags: silverlight-4.0, windows-phone-7

In my application i am using MultiselectList for selecting a list of student information. Here my issue is that, I am using a black background image for my page,

Because of this in white theme, the checkbox portion is invisible. I try to edit the template of checkbox item in Blend, but failed, while editing the template its populating a huge chunk of code in XAML.

While editing template instead of style its generating Template (I edited the Multilist Item using Blend).

In the real application i am using itemtemplate and assign the resource to this item template.

So I don't know where to assign this template, and where to edit in that template to change my checkbox colour, this is a blocker issue for me, my friend told me that without theme support the app won’t pass market place submission.

Comment: Template editing you could do in visual designer too rather than xaml editing. Find appropriate elements in elements tree and change their colors accordingly.

Comment: Don't change the CheckBox template, unless you know how to do it with proper theme support. The standard control layout is almost always better due to it being more intuitive and native to the platform.

Comment: @Claus : Then how i can achieve the same in my app.One issue is that i can’t neglect the Background image its my clients requirement

Comment: Ku6opr @ Ku6opr @ Your answer is just like showing moon and telling about the water. At least please give me a detailed information including some code snip..

Answer (score 1):

Doing what you want to do, ie. editing the color of the checkbox, depending on the theme and background selected would be too much work. Have you tried using the default styles that come with Silverlight? For example, In this case, PhoneContrastbackgroundColor would be a good choice.

XAML code

```
<DataTemplate x:Key="whatever">
<TextBlock Text="ItemName"/>
<CheckBox BackgroundColor="{StaticResource PhoneContrastbackgroundColor}"/>
</DataTemplate>
```

Comment: if you want more info about all the themes available, there is a comprehensive list here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff769552(v=vs.92).aspx